# PyQT : How to activate command link button if at least one element is checked in a treeview

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt, treeview

I want to activate command link button if at least one element is checked in a treeview.

I tried this method but it is not working well :

```
def activate_launch_button(self):

    model = self.scenarios.model()
    checked_indexes = model.match(model.index(0, 0), QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole,QtCore.Qt.Checked, -1,QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly | QtCore.Qt.MatchRecursive)
    print checked_indexes
    if checked_indexes != []:
        self.launch_btn.setEnabled(True)
```

The problem with this method is the button is activated only after closing the window. I don't understand why.
For caling this method I put it in two methods :

```
def show(self):
    self.project.load()
    if self.project.tranus_project:
        self.tranus_folder.setText(self.project.tranus_project.path)
    self.activate_launch_button()
    self.launch_options_TRANUS()
    super(OptionsTRANUSDialog, self).show()


def select_tranus_folder(self):

    folder = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select directory")
    if folder:
        self.tranus_folder.setText(folder)
        if not self.project.load_tranus_folder(folder):
            self.tranus_folder.setText('')
        self.reload_scenarios()
        self.activate_launch_button()
```

I really want that the command link button should be activated when at least one element of treeview is checked and to be inactive if there is no element checked.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to connect activate_launch_button() with a signal from the view widget indicating the checked status has changed. Without knowing how you implemented the treeview with check boxes, I'm not sure what signal that is. With a plain QCheckBox it would be stateChanged.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I implemeted treeview with checkboxes by puttings items of treeview checkable using this method : item.setCheckable(True) with item is a QstandardItem from QstandardItemModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found solution to all my problems :

```
def activate_launch_button(self):

    model = self.scenarios.model()
    model.itemChanged.connect(self.check_configure)
def check_configure(self,item):

        model = self.scenarios.model()
        index = model.indexFromItem(item)

        if index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole) != index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole + QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole):

            if index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)!= QtCore.Qt.Unchecked :

                self.count_check+=1
                model.setData(index,index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole),QtCore.Qt.UserRole + QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)

            else :

                self.count_check-=1
                model.setData(index,index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole),QtCore.Qt.UserRole + QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
                print self.count_check

            self.launch_btn.setEnabled(self.count_check>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a partial solution to my problem, I used the signal itemChanged http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemChanged

```
def activate_launch_button(self):

    model = self.scenarios.model()
    model.itemChanged.connect(self.check_configure)

 def check_configure(self):
    self.launch_btn.setEnabled(True)
```

It activates the button when there is one element is checked however when I uncheck all, the button doesn't become inactive. How can I solve this issue ?